# ViewPager with Database access in every fragment and how to avoid close() errors

Tags: android, database

Are DB close errors dangerous? I have a viewpager with 3 fragments that all access the DB. But I get an error about closing the DB everytime.  How am I supposed to control this if all 3 fragments need the DB at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should control db connections of all your components. Consider keeping one DB connection for entire Fragment Activity, which contains your viewpager. 
Erros can cause db connection failure.

Comment: I fixed it by using the parent activity to always control the Database access open and closing and using getActivity() to get the database helper object in order to avoid multiple opening and closing of the db.  Online documentation isn't clear the best way to pass or share this type of object since the Fragment has to have an empty constructor and you can't store a complex object in the Bundle for later use.